# GDM locale problems

Tags: 10.04, gdm, locale

I have two problems with GDM on Ubuntu 10.04.

The first is with locales.
In my system I have defined:

```
$ cat /etc/environment 
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="es_ES:es:en_US:en"

$ cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE="es_ES:es:en_US:en"

$ cat /var/lib/locales/supported.d/local 
es_ES UTF-8
es_ES.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US UTF-8
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
```

But when I enter in gnome desktop:

```
$ locale
LANG=es_ES
LANGUAGE=es_ES:es:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="es_ES"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES"
LC_TIME="es_ES"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES"
LC_PAPER="es_ES"
LC_NAME="es_ES"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES"
LC_ALL=
```

I have deleted ~/.dmrc and I have restarted the system but nothing.
GDM login screen also doesn't permit change this setting.

However, in the text terminals (*tty1,...*):

```
$ locale
LANG=es_ES.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=es_ES:es:en_US:en
LC_CTYPE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="es_ES.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

The solution to problem is to edit .drmc file, but I think this isn't the right way.

> **Why doesn't GDM read/apply the system locales?
>  Why don't I see,
>   in GDM login screen, the box to change
>   the locale?**

Comment: Do you have the appropriate packages installed? Like language-support-en?

Comment: In my case is language-support-es. I haven't installed it but this package only contains document files:
"/usr/share/doc/language-support-es, 
/usr/share/doc/language-support-es/changelog.gz, 
/usr/share/doc/language-support-es/copyright"

Comment: Besides the documentation it also has dependencies that contain the real data...

Comment: Do you actually have the `en` locales installed?

Answer (score 1):

The language selector in GDM is gone:

- https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=671528

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to ensure you have each locale installed on the machine. Not all locales are bundled with the install - and if the packages (and the packages dependancies) don't exist on the system it will revert to the default first installed locale - `en`

Answer (score -1):

Have you read this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Locale

This may help you.

Comment: Yes, I have read. But it says nothing about gdm and gnome session. And I have configured the locales correctly, as it says that document.